# How do I load an XML file using Crawler?

Tags: symfony, web-crawler, symfony-2.1

I need to load xml files and store them into a database. I'm using Symfony 2.1 as a framework and this framweork comes with a great tool - the crawler. It makes using XPATH easy.

How do I load XML files using this crawler?

Have you any a good tutorial showing how to do that?

Comment: If you use Symfony 2.1, you don't have to add the tag Symfony 2.0.

Comment: What about `$someEntity->someAttribute = file_get_contents('some_file.xml')`? I mean you don't need to crawl the file to be able to read it and store it. If you still need to use the crawler, [this](http://symfony.com/doc/master/components/dom_crawler.html) is its documentation, in case you haven't read it.

Comment: To load xml file using this crawler use "addXmlContent" method

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
$document = new \DOMDocument();
$document->loadXml(file_get_contents('my_file.xml'));

$crawler = new Crawler();
$crawler->addDocument($document);
```

or this?

```
$crawler = new Crawler();
$crawler->addXmlContent(file_get_contents('my_file.xml'));
```

Read more on DomCrawler component and how to load content into it: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html#adding-the-content